# How to disable warn about some unused params, but keep "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars" rule

Tags: eslint, typescript-eslint

I want to disable no unused params warning in some cases but keep "unused vars" rule.

For example here I would want to leave arguments in place to see what is passed to resolver:

```
const Query = objectType({
  name: 'Query',
  definition(t) {
    t.field('test', {
      type: 'Test',
      resolve: (root, args, ctx) => {
        const x = 1

        return { id: 1, time: new Date().toString() }
      },
    })
  },
})
```

I get warnings:

```
26:17  warning  'root' is defined but never used        @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
26:23  warning  'args' is defined but never used        @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
26:29  warning  'ctx' is defined but never used         @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
27:15  warning  'x' is assigned a value but never used  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
```

ESLint config:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: { ecmaVersion: 2020, ecmaFeatures: { jsx: true } },
  env: {
    browser: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: ['plugin:react-hooks/recommended', 'eslint:recommended', 'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended', 'plugin:react/recommended'],
  settings: {
    react: {
      version: 'detect',
    },
  },
  rules: {
    '@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function': 'off',
    'react/react-in-jsx-scope': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': 'off',
    'react/prop-types': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types': 'off',
    'no-unused-vars': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': ['off'],
  },
  ignorePatterns: ['**/generated/*'],
}
```

I was trying to disable it somehow, but found only this option that disables everything:

```
'no-unused-vars': 'off',
'@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': ['off'],
```

Answer (score 328, accepted):

Only way that I found is to use [ignore pattern](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars#options) `argsIgnorePattern` in rule options. If your variable is unused, just add underscore `_ctx` and ESLint will ignore it, but `no-unused-vars` rule will still work for other values. When you will need to use this value, just remove underscore `ctx`.

```json
// .eslintrc.json
{
  // ...
  "rules": {
    // note you must disable the base rule
    // as it can report incorrect errors
    "no-unused-vars": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": [
      "warn", // or "error"
      {
        "argsIgnorePattern": "^_",
        "varsIgnorePattern": "^_",
        "caughtErrorsIgnorePattern": "^_"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You can change this pattern `^_` as you like using RegExp.

Example:

```
const _a = 'unused, with underscore, no warning'
const b = 'unused, no underscore, warning'
```

Comment: To ignore unused variables that begin with an underscore use `varsIgnorePattern` instead of `argsIgnorePattern`.

Comment: @uladzimir it should work: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars#argsignorepattern  note that you mast disable basic rule if you use typescript one

Comment: the "issue" though is that all of a sudden, if you use it, it won't warn you that you are using a variable that is supposed to stay unused (and thus you should probably rename | remove the `_`)

Comment: @NathanGouy there is no problem in using variable named `_a` as it only marked like that for eslint and it will be hard not to see underscore when reviewing or coding.

Comment: Where does this file live?

Comment: @Antonio in eslint congig rules: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files#using-configuration-files

Comment: sadly the "it will be hard not to see" is very relative to each individual.
Rules are better than human eyes that's why they are here.

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/586

Answer (score 6):

To add to [ZiiMakc's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64067915/8910547), to allow `_` exclusively for unused vars, and still allow __ for 'private' used vars:

here is a link for [sandbox](https://typescript-eslint.io/play/#ts=4.9.5&fileType=.tsx&esQuery=N4IgZglgNgLgpgJxALhCAvkA&code=MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MAUB9AhgGhgIwEoUA%2BGAbxgHoqYBTADwAc7hYB5AaQCgYZRIIADZ0AdEJABzNEQDc3AL4xu3AdBjYsKGACZZ1WoxZsYXbghBoAjHh2EVa2BZ3a0uAsWRlKNes1awdABOQSBBAFwwAAYWUTBYYAAmMADkWCnxQXQwAK5gORB0ibz84BDCYhLSRIoOZbAY%2BFhBrth4RKQUBn7GgSFheI3NMACWELmFxXxqFeJSMoTyCtxDQda29qr1Gk0AXq3ujZ7e3UYB9P1Bg-ij4wVFJTMic9JHS3WQsADajYONIFghABdbRfGzoNoaXbHCiPMqzKqYaFLIHybi%2BJ6VeZvFQYf6A9a6TaOAhhbSULCRcH4SI6PDASIAZhgyxJFMikNEXKy6iUqHwZOUmJeaB5UEIQA&eslintrc=N4KABGBEBOCuA2BTAzpAXGUEKQAIBcBPABxQGNoBLY-AWhXkoDt8B6JgQwFtmBzWsgHsmAN0QtKw9GADa4bDkTRog6JAA08hVgXZIyREjL5V0ubt2RiHaN0T4lGrRagiblDgCMkkZwoC6mi5QSBwAJnwAqkxhSshC0IjSMIgAjrCUiU7BkABmqlwc%2BGZ%2BlmR28ADCHAa%2BwYGlOFyCEbmUcSXBOLBMsAZhdS7%2BpQC%2BQbo6FvqGiMamGOZdVjZ2DmrjOW5UXj6NYA05oRFMvNGx0PGqSRiQHPDwggDuACKCsN5JG5b50IXFC3scOUuIZqrU9sMLCNnAc9AQSOQqDR6MhGCx2IJaD0%2BogwrQtqgAVMlCp1qVJpYbLxCVA7vBsi5btBqQBJXhMK4ABSKayYyQAegB9BlTAlsjmJbn4XkC4VfBSQcqwXgAC3wAFFlKpkOKuTylHybkLBgpoQF5NCRkA&tsconfig=N4KABGBEDGD2C2AHAlgGwKYCcDyiAuysAdgM6QBcYoEEkJemy0eAcgK6qoDCAFutAGsylBm3TgwAXxCSgA&tokens=false)

```js
{
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/naming-convention": [
      "error",
      {
        "selector": [
          "parameter",
          "variable"
        ],
        "leadingUnderscore": "require",
        "format": ["camelCase"],
        "modifiers": [
          "unused"
        ]
      },
      {
        "selector": [
          "parameter",
          "variable"
        ],
        "leadingUnderscore": "allowDouble",
        "format": [
          "camelCase"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": [
      "error",
      {
        "args": "all",
        "argsIgnorePattern": "^_",
        "varsIgnorePattern": "^_",
        "caughtErrorsIgnorePattern": "^_"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not work

Comment: Which part doesn't work / what do you see you are not expecting to see or vice-versa ?

Comment: the rules posted do not "allow `_` exclusively for unused vars". If a used variable has an underscore in the name, eslint does not give any error or warning.

Comment: Additionally, the "_*" regex matches every single variable name, so that first selector is effectively doing nothing.

Comment: The second selector is also redundant given the "no-usused-vars" rule. So the entire "naming-convention" rule in this answer is not providing any additional checking.

Comment: you are right, I've played around in sandbox here. https://shorturl.at/adzX6
I've updated my response

Comment: I don't even think we need the first part actually