# Eslint returns with no-unused-vars

Tags: typescript, eslint

I have setup eslint to warn me on unsed vars

```
rules: {
  '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': ['error', { args: 'none' }],
}
```

Now I have a typescript class which look like this:

```
import { User } from './user';

export class MyClass {
  async myMethod(): Promise<User> {
    // Some code
  }
}
```

When I run eslint I get this error

```
error  'User' is defined but never used  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
```

Why is eslint warning me? In my eyes the variable is used.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable warn about some unused params, but keep "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars" rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64052318/how-to-disable-warn-about-some-unused-params-but-keep-typescript-eslint-no-un)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, we see only the type Promise, which doesn't mean that you are using User in your Method, but only to define a type.
Eslint is expected :

```
import { IUser} from './user'; // interface for User object
import { User } from './user'; // User object

export class MyClass {
  async myMethod(User: string): Promise<IUser> {
    // Some code with User parameter
  }
}
```

Your Eslint rule will apply only on User object, and not on the interface.

some readings: https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/future-javascript/promise

Answer (score 1):

You must disable the base rule as it can report incorrect errors. Reference: [@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars](http:////%20note%20you%20must%20disable%20the%20base%20rule%20as%20it%20can%20report%20incorrect%20errors%20%20%20%22no-unused-vars%22:%20%22off%22,%20%20%20%22@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars%22:%20%5B%22error%22%5D)

```
  "no-unused-vars": "off",
  "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": ["error", { args: "none" }]
```

User.ts

```
export class User {
    name: string;
}
```

MyClass.ts

```
import { User } from './User'

export class MyClass {
    async myMethod(): Promise<User> {
        // Some code
    }
}
```

Also this is my bare minimum eslint config

```
module.exports = {
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin"],
  "env": {
    "node": true
  },
  "extends": "eslint:recommended",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "rules": {
    "no-unused-vars": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": ['error'],
  }
}
```

package.json dependencies

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint hello.ts"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/eslint": "7.2.4",
    "@types/node": "13.7.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.14.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.14.1",
    "eslint": "7.18.0",
    "ts-node": "8.6.2",
    "typescript": "3.8.3"
  }
}
```