# How to disable warnings for identifiers prefixed with underscore (_)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, eslint, eslintrc

#### Background and introduction

As a developer in ReactJS, I highly appreciate the automated help I get from [ESLint](https://eslint.org) on code issues such as unused identifiers.

I have [a small example project in a zip file](https://github.com/henk9/Henke/raw/main/StackOverflow-Q71384606/71384606.zip) for experimenting with ESLint. <sup>1</sup>

Even without explicit ESLint rules, Visual Studio Code indicates what identifiers are unused by showing them in less vibrant colors. 
In the screenshot below, `unUsedArgument` and `unUsedVariable` would have been displayed in about the same color as `prevToggle`, had they been used.

[image: Even without ESLint, VS Code indicates what identifiers are unused.]

---

`App.js` :

```js
import React, { useCallback, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Button from './components/UI/Button/Button';

function App(unUsedArgument) {
  const [unUsedVariable, setShowParagraph] = useState(true);
  const showParagraphFcn = useCallback(() => {
    setShowParagraph((prevToggle) => !prevToggle);
  },[]);
  console.log('App RUNNING');
  return (
    <div className='app'>
      <h1>Hi there!</h1>
      <Button onClick={showParagraphFcn}>A Button</Button>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

After downloading [the mentioned zip file](https://github.com/henk9/Henke/raw/main/StackOverflow-Q71384606/71384606.zip), running `npm install` and then `npm start`, a web page opens in my default web browser.
Pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> makes it look as below.
<sup>2</sup>

[image: Without ESLint, the browser displays no warnings or errors.]

The screenshot shows that – without ESLint – no errors or warnings are displayed in the console of the browser. 
This is despite the fact that both `unUsedArgument` and `unUsedVariable` are indeed *unused*.

---

`package.json` – to begin with :

```json
{
  "name": "disable-warnings-for-variables-prefixed-with-underscore",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version"
    ]
  },
  "overrides": {
    "nth-check": "^2.1.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.31"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11"
  }
}
```

In addition, I have an `eslintConfig.json` file whose contents were in `package.json`, but which I deliberately removed from there to see how the behavior would be affected.

`eslintConfig.json` :

```json
,
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  }
```

When running `npm install`, the ESLint packages are downloaded. 
This happens because [`react-scripts` depends indirectly on several ESLint packages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71423006).

Here is how to run ESLint from the command line :

```
npx eslint **/*.js
```

The first three lines of the response say that ESLint was installed, but not configured :

```
Oops! Something went wrong! :(
ESLint: 8.53.0
ESLint couldn't find a configuration file.
```

My next action is therefore to add the `eslintConfig` attribute back into `package.json`. <sup>3</sup> 
After doing that, the result of running `npx eslint **/*.js` is :

[image: With ESLint, the command line displays one warning.]

The warning reads :

`'unUsedVariable' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars`

Thus, without any further configurations, ESLint warns about the unused *variable*, but not about the unused *argument*.
I would prefer to be warned about *both* identifiers that are unused. 
In addition, I would like to have the option to disable ESLint warnings for unused arguments and variables *that start with an underscore* (`_`). 
Having such a rule would mean that I could easily turn off these warnings – permanently or temporarily – by simply prefixing the identifier with `_` (an underscore).

---

In Visual Studio Code, I can achieve this by adding a specially designed ESLint comment. <sup>4</sup>

```js
/*eslint no-unused-vars: ["warn",{"argsIgnorePattern":
"^_","varsIgnorePattern": "^_"}]*/
```

[image: In VS Code, an ESLint comment can prevent warnings about unused identifiers prefixed with an underscore.]

#### The question I want to ask

This does what I want, but at the expense of cluttering my JavaScript code with ugly ESLint comments in all files.
I would prefer to set the ESLint rules *once, for the whole project* so that all JavaScript files automatically adhere to these rules.

***How can I get this without scattering ESLint comments all over my JavaScript code?***

### References

- [ESLint | home page](https://eslint.org)
- [Zip file containing the project files needed to reproduce my findings](https://github.com/henk9/Henke/raw/main/StackOverflow-Q71384606/71384606.zip)
- [Create React App (CRA)](https://create-react-app.dev)
- [Create React App is no longer maintained](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/12974)
- [The package `react-scripts` depends indirectly on ESLint packages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71423006)
- [VS Code ESLint extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint)
- [Installing ESLint globally is *not recommended*](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/getting-started#global-install).

---

<sup>1</sup>
The project was originally created as a [Create React App (CRA)](https://create-react-app.dev). 
I have since deliberately removed the `eslintConfig` attribute in `package.json` for demonstrative purposes, and simplified it by removing everything related to *test*. 
The obscure package `@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object` is included just to silence a warning in the command line, now that [Create React App is no longer maintained](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/12974).

<sup>2</sup>
For me, the `npm install` command has taken any time from 1 to 11 minutes to complete. 
The `npm install` command downloads and installs all Node.js packages listed in the `package.json` file. 
The `npm start` command starts a local web server and opens the `public/index.html` file in your default web browser, in my case Google Chrome Version 98.0.4758.102, 64-bit, running on Windows 10. 
When you want to close the server, do so it by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

<sup>3</sup>
No need to run `npm install` this time, as no packages are affected.

<sup>4</sup>
This is likely true for many other text editors and IDEs as well, such as for example WebStorm by JetBrains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***How can I get this without scattering ESLint comments all over my JavaScript code?***

Just add `rules` under the `eslintConfig` attribute, to make `package.json` look as follows. <sup>1</sup>

`package.json` :

```json
{
  "name": "disable-warnings-for-variables-prefixed-with-underscore",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app",
    "rules": {
      "no-unused-vars": [
        "warn",
        {
          "argsIgnorePattern": "^_",
          "varsIgnorePattern": "^_"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "overrides": {
    "nth-check": "^2.1.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.31"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11"
  }
}
```

Now you can remove the ESLint comment from `App.js` and still get the desired behavior.

Check to see that you were successful:

```
npx eslint **/*.js
```

Expect to see:

[image: With rules under eslintConfig in package.json, both unused identifiers are warned about.]

If your text editor (VS Code in my case) is still open, make sure that you restart it before you expect to see this new behavior.
Play around in your text editor by adding and removing an underscore prefix to see the warning go away and appear again.

#### Reference

- [How to disable warnings about unused identifiers (TypeScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64052318)

---

<sup>1</sup>
In this case, there's no need to run `npm install`.
Just adding the `rules` attribute under `eslintConfig` is enough.